# Anyroad and Anyway

Tags: meaning, etymology, slang

As far as I know, ***anyway*** is a common word used by both American and British English speakers to mean *in any case*, *nevertheless*, etc. I never thought much about the word until I noticed that British English speakers sometimes use ***anyroad*** the same way.

If I *had* thought about it, I'd probably have said the *way* in *anyway* meant something like *manner,* or whichever way, or manner, in which the situation is considered.

But learning of *anyroad* as a synonym for *anyway*, I thought about the fact that *way* is another word for street or road. Thus, we can also way that *anyway* means "any (metaphorical) road you want to go down in considering the situation."

My initial impression was that *anyroad* was a word invented as an amusing alternate for *anyway*, unexpectedly playing on the synonymous relationship between *way* and *road*, but perhaps there was no humo(u)r intended.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anyroad) identifies *anyroad* as Northern England dialect and British slang, originating 1885 or 1890. What other specifics relate to the origins of *anyroad*?

Comment: Also see  [How did 'anyway' become 'anyways,' anyway?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/10847)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OED says, *s.v.* **road**, in its sense no. 9:

> *Eng. regional* (chiefly *north.* in later use). Way, manner. Freq. as ***no road***: (in) no way or manner; ***some road***: (in) some way or manner.
>   See also ANY ROAD *adv*..

However, the link (ANY ROAD *adv*) fails, and there does not seem to be an entry for either **anyroad** or **any road**, though the former does occur incidentally in a citation from 1932 (for **mill-house**).

It certainly agrees with my perception that it is a Northern use. I hear *anyroad*, or sometimes *anyroad up*, here in Yorkshire, but did not hear it when I was growing up in the South.

Comment: +1 I wonder if you can explain what is meant by "in later use"?" Later than what? And was *road* meaning way or manner initially used nationally and subsequently only in the North, according to that entry?

Comment: @sarah I don't know for sure, but I'm guessing it means that the word retains/retained usage in the North later than elsewhere in England.

Comment: @sarah: it means that this is a regional use in England, formerly widespread, but more recently mostly in the North.

Comment: this does not provide an answer. It still seems like a pun on *way*, which is at the heart of the question, and no judgement has been made either road. OP accepting the answer implies to me they accepted that this is just what *road* always meant, so your answer is in effect misleading, and unlikely to become substantiated. There is good reason to see *way* having been associated with *wh-* words originally, especially *why*, long before Old English (not too far though, if Lat *via* and *quo* would be difficult to explain as dissimilation). You might want to *weigh* in on that.

Comment: @vectory: 1. It does provide an answer. 2. _Road_ and _way_ have a large area of overlap in their meanings. This question is about an area of overlap which is current in some dialects, but not in standard English. 3. Your fringe speculations about etymology are wholly irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 6):

Just to supplement @ColinFine's answer:

[Oxford Dictionaries Online (ODO)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/any?q=anyroad#any__17) has:

> **any road (up)**
>   chiefly *Northern English* informal term for ANYWAY.
>   *any road, I’m sure you’ll make a go of it*

[OneLook Dictionary Search](http://www.onelook.com/?w=anyroad&ls=b) lists 6 links, but none seems to add anything new. Some of them state that it is a *northern English* term, and some (I think mainly the American-orientated ones) merely state *British*.

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=any&searchmode=none) lists origins for *any* and for about 12 *any-* words, but *anyroad* is not included.